# Handle exception both in coroutine handler and try-catch block

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

If we have for example base handler like

```
protected val baseHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        handleError(e)
}
```

And execute our code via try-catch block

```
scope.launch(baseHandler){
  try{
      throw ...
     }
     catch(e:Exception) {
}
```

Is it possible to handle exception firstly in catch block and as a fallback in base handler?
The goal of this code is to have a base exception handler for all project coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

The `CoroutineExceptionHandler` you've created and passed in will be used for exceptions that aren't handled in the coroutine.

For example, if you want to catch one specific type of `Exception`, and handle all other exceptions in the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, you can `try-catch` for just that type:

```
GlobalScope.launch(baseHandler) {
    try {
        throw IllegalStateException("oh no it failed")
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        // Handles the exception
    }
}
```

If an exception other than `IllegalStateException` is thrown within the `try` block, that will be propagated to your handler.

Alternatively, you can catch things in the `catch` branch, but then re-throw them if you can't handle it there, and want to leave it up to the handler instead:

```
GlobalScope.launch(baseHandler) {
    try {
        // Code that can throw exceptions
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (/* some condition */) {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```